# How to insert multiple parameters into an sql statement with and without single quotes

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write a dynamic sql statement that takes the schema name and other variables into an SQL statement.  My QA database and production database have different schema name.  I have a variable called 'dbschema' that can pull the qa schema in my qa environment and the production schema in the production environment.

Example:

- QA environment: schema_qa
- Production environment: schema_production

MySQL query:

```
          select *
            from :schema.student s
            where convert_tz(s.date,'GMT','US/Central') >= :start_date
                    and convert_tz(s.date,'GMT','US/Central') < :end_date
```

The variables I need to bind are: start_date, end_date, and schema.  start_date and end_date need single quotes and schema does not need quotes.

Current python code:

```
df = pd.read_sql(text(sql).bindparams(start_date=start_date,
                                      end_date=end_date,
                                      schema=schema),
                                      con=engine)
```

I am hoping for the query to format below:

```
          select *
          from schema.student s
          where convert_tz(s.date,'GMT','US/Central') >= '2023-12-01'
                    and convert_tz(s.date,'GMT','US/Central') < '2024-01-01'
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''schema'.student s\n
```

Comment: You can't bind tables/identifiers. You can't control db/schema at the db connection level? I would write date `where` with a `between`, `convert_tz(s.date,'GMT','US/Central') between :start_date and :end_date`

Comment: Remember, part of the point of prepared statements (to which bind parameters apply) is allowing parsing **and optimization** to be done before the statement is actually used. The database engine can't decide how to optimize a query if it doesn't know which table and column names that query applies to, and thus can't look up the set of available indices and the results from last time they had vacuuming / statistics collection performed.

Comment: That said, if you're using sqlalchemy, it'll safely quote table names for you, so you shouldn't have any (security-related) reason to be using bind parameters for table or column names anyhow.